# How to get row when matching multiple AND?

Tags: sql

I have a little problem, I do have a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t_ot_prestation` (
  `id_ot` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_prestation` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_ot`,`id_prestation`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

What I would like to get is to get distinct id_ot according to multiple id_prestation. For instance, I was expecting :

```
SELECT id_ot
FROM `t_ot_prestation`
WHERE `id_prestation` =723
AND `id_prestation` =1177;
```

To give me all id_ot having 2 rows with 723 and 1177. But this isn't the case.

What am I doing wrong ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work, because no row could match that condition.  Instead, use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT id_ot
FROM `t_ot_prestation`
GROUP BY id_ot
HAVING sum(case when `id_prestation` = 723 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and 
       sum(case when `id_prestation` = 1177 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of matches to each value.  The `> 0` is simply saying that at least one row matches a particular value.

Comment: This does the trick, but looks very complicated for such simple request... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes user3488440, you are right, that's a bit too complicated, but both shows a good way to address your particular problem as well as problems with more criteria. You should use WHERE id_presentation IN (723,1177) though, to access the desired records fast (rather than scan the full table). Then, as you are only looking at two different values, use HAVING MIN(id_presentation) = 723 and MAX(id_presentation) = 1177.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause is looked at per record. There is no single record that has both id_prestation =723 and id_prestation = 1177, of course.

Here is one way to solve this (provided your dbms supports INTERSECT):

```
SELECT id_ot
FROM `t_ot_prestation`
WHERE `id_prestation` =723
INTERSECT
SELECT id_ot
FROM `t_ot_prestation`
WHERE `id_prestation` =1177;
```

Other ways that come to mind are: EXISTS clause, IN clause, self join, group by.

Comment: That's true. When looking for a MySQL solution, you should tag your request with "mysql" :-)

Answer (score 0):

As has been identified by others, there will be no rows that match both of those conditions, here is another approach:

```
SELECT id_ot
FROM `t_ot_prestation`
WHERE `id_prestation` IN (723, 1177)
```

where you are looking for a match in a set of possibilities within the `IN` clause.

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. The IN clause will give me every id_ot where id_prestation is 723 OR 1177. What I need is 723 AND 1177.
Thanks for answering though :)

Comment: @user3488440 - so you're wanting to check whether there is a row for 723, but only if there is also a different row for 1177? Do these rows share any common attributes, `id_ot`, perhaps?

Comment: Yes they do have the id_ot. But I solved it using RIGHT JOIN as I know (now) that this is a "many-to-many" table type ;)